# Java generics capture inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes, nested-generics

I have this code:

```
public class UndirectedGraphImpl<N> {
    [...]
    public Iterator<Edge<N>> adj(N v) {
        return new AdjIterator(v);
    }

    private class AdjIterator implements Iterator<Edge<N>> {
        [...]
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Graph<Integer> g = new UndirectedGraphImpl<Integer>();
        [...]
        Iterator<Edge<Integer>> it = g.adj(4);
    }

}
```

At compile time I get this error:

```
error: incompatible types

        Iterator<Edge<Integer>> it = g.adj(4);
                                          ^
  required: Iterator<Edge<Integer>>
  found:    Iterator<CAP#1>
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Edge<Integer> from capture of ? extends Edge<Integer>
```

If I replace that line with

```
Iterator<Edge<Integer>> it = (Iterator<Edge<Integer>>)g.adj(4);
```

then I get an unchecked cast warning, but I don't understand why the compiler capture that "? extends Edge<Integer>". Someone con explain me what it happens and how to fix this?

EDIT: This is the Graph interface implemented by UndirectedGraphImpl class

```
public interface Graph<N> extends Iterable<N> {
    [...]
    Iterator<? extends Edge<N>> adj(N v);
    [...]
}
```

Comment: How is the method declared?

Comment: Which method do you mean? "adj" method is in the first snippet

Comment: You are invoking it on `g` so it must be the one in `Graph`, and also it should be implemented/extended by `UndirectedGraphImpl` but it doesn't in your first snippet.

Comment: Can you post the Graph class too please?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. It's defined as Iterator<? extends Edge<N>> adj(N v); in Graph interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning the type `Iterator<? extends Edge<Integer>>`, but you're trying to assign it to a variable of type `Iterator<Edge<Integer>>`.

The CAP thing you see comes from the process of capture conversion, which essentially tries to remove wildcards from returned types. But in this case they're still incompatible.

Capture conversion is defined in section 5.1.10 of the JLS in case you're interested in seeing the details.

Comment: So if I declare g as a Graph<Type> I have to use Iterator<? extends Edge<Type>>, while if I want to use Iterator<Edge<Type>> I have to declare g variable as an UndirectedGraphImpl<Type>, right?

Comment: Either that or change the interface to be more consistent if possible.